# sendmail Authorization failed in cron jobs

Tags: cron, sendmail

When I search for 'cron' using grep in `/var/log/syslog` I get some lines as follows:

```
Oct  2 11:10:02 hplaptop cron[141532]: sendmail: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor d5sm1019803wrb.28 - gsmtp)
Oct  2 11:11:01 hplaptop cron[141579]: sendmail: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor i11sm1042743wre.32 - gsmtp)
Oct  2 11:12:01 hplaptop cron[141623]: sendmail: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor x2sm1028990wrl.13 - gsmtp)
Oct  2 11:13:02 hplaptop cron[141662]: sendmail: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor f23sm1006111wmf.6 - gsmtp)
```

I've never used that program or a similar command to send emails. What do these error messages mean? is it a malware trying to send mail?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @roaima: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Do you know what mail program is installed? If not... `ls -l /usr/*bin/sendmail` outputs what please? What about `ps -ef | grep '[m]ail'`? I need to see what you've got installed so I can identify where the message queue is, and in turn point you to reading the unsent messages. Hopefully this will help you identify what tried to send them, and you can then address that unexpected source

Comment: @roaima: The output of the first command is: 
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 feb. 24  2020 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> ssmtp` the second command returns nothing.

Comment: Ok. `ssmtp` doesn't manage a message queue - it delivers a message or simply discards it. Is there anything useful in `/var/log/mail.log`?

Comment: @roaima: there is 3955 lines in that log file, but it seems that only these 3 lines are repeating:
```Oct  4 00:01:01 hplaptop sSMTP[109160]: Creating SSL connection to host
Oct  4 00:01:01 hplaptop sSMTP[109160]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Oct  4 00:01:01 hplaptop sSMTP[109160]: Authorization failed (534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor q15sm6711309wrr.8 - gsmtp)```

Answer (score 1):

Your Gmail account is set to use [Two Factor Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Two-factor_authentication&redirect=no) (2FA). When Sendmail client sends correct username and password to Google mail servers, Google responds with a second authentication challenge, that is 2FA. Then Sendmail client does not know where to get the 2FA response from.

To fix this (not the best option though) is to disable 2FA and allow less secure applications to access your Gmail account. More info [her](https://myaccount.google.com/security)e and [here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/)

If you have developer skills, consider [this](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en) or this [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/a-beginners-guide-to-the-google-gmail-api-and-its-documentation-c73495deff08)

Comment: I've mentioned that I've never setup an email on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2-Step Verification problem (as Bruce already pointed out). To get around it you need to create an unique App Password, which then can be used by your application as authentication at login. The generated App Password is longer and more "cumbersome" to remember than most "normal" user passwords are.

NOTE: The 2-Step Verification should remain ENABLED when using App Passwords

You can read more about it here at Google: [Sign in to GMail using app passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833)

Comment: I've mentioned that I've never setup an email on my machine. 2FA of what?